# Inserting and removing a character from a string

Tags: regex, elixir

Lets say i have a string "customer" and i want to add `s` at the end

`customers`

And i have another string like `"users"`. how can i remove `s` at the end to make it `user`.

What will be the best approach?

Comment: In the spirit of "teaching a person to fish"--adding characters to the end of a string is called _concatenation_.  Removing characters is usually called _truncation_.  Also, be careful of the term _best_ because there are a lot of ways to decide what's "best".  Shortest code?  Fastest execution?  Those may be two different approaches altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding characters

```
"customer" <> "s"
```

#### Removing characters

Elixir idiomatic:

```
String.trim_trailing("users", "s")
#⇒ "user"
```

More efficient for long strings:

```
with [_ | tail] <- "users" |> to_charlist |> :lists.reverse,
  do: tail |> :lists.reverse |> to_string
```

Most efficient (credits to @Dogbert):

```
str = "users"
sz = :erlang.byte_size(str),       
:erlang.binary_part(str, {0, sz - 1})
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not most efficient. It's `O(n)` while a solution using `binary_part` and `byte_size` will be `O(1)`.

Comment: @Dogbert I am not sure I follow how `binary_part` might be `O(1)`.

Comment: `binary_part` will share the memory of the original binary. It will only be copied if you try to prepend something or append twice. http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#id66452

Comment: @Dogbert indeed; thank you very much for the link I somehow had that missed before. Updated.

Comment: I know you love it, but there's no need to use `with` here. :D

Comment: @Dogbert your solution ⇒ your rules. Updated :) I believe it helps a young heap garbage collector.